# simple logic to use only one operator to construct a function

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

So I was doing some of the problems on the book for discrete mathematics and I encountered this problem:

We define a new operator ⊙ as follows:

x ...y.... x⊙y

F... F... T

F... T... F

T... F... F

T... T... F

Using ONLY this operator construct functions that evaluate to the following boolean functions:

f(p,q) = p ^ q

Can anyone explain step by step or from the scratch how to tackle this one? I am new to this logic mathematics..

All I can think of is x⊙y = ~(p∨q)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simple logic math question from logic math newbie](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486900/simple-logic-math-question-from-logic-math-newbie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that $x\odot y$ is equivalent to $\neg (x\vee y)$ (I assume the switch from $x$ and $y$ to $p$ and $q$ was a typo), but this isn't the most natural way of attacking it: it would be better to view $x\odot y$ as $$(\neg x)\wedge (\neg y).$$ From here it should be clear that, if we could only build *negation* out of $\odot$, we'd know how to build $\wedge$ out of $\odot$. So: using $\odot$, can you express "$\neg x$"?

Comment: how and where did you get (¬x)∧(¬y) ?

Comment: Well, $x\odot y$ is true iff $x$ is false and $y$ is false, so . . .

Comment: im so sorry for asking all this newbie question, but how do you know if ¬x is x⊙x ???

Comment: @cohsta Aha! Yes, $x\odot x$ is indeed equivalent to $\neg x$! So, now that you know this, can you build $\wedge$ out of $\odot$?

Comment: but how do you know if negation of x is x⊙x?? And also, when you plug in, it is (x⊙x) ^ (y⊙y). how do you get rid of ^?

Comment: @cohsta To your first question: look at the truth table. When is "$\neg x$" true? When is "$x\odot x$" true? To your second: try going the other way; I showed you how to express $\odot$ in terms of $\wedge$ and $\neg$, can you show me how to express $\wedge$ in terms of $\odot$ and $\neg$?